# Find first record for each Id SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the below table with ID and Number columns

```
ID Number 
1 34534 
1 45345 
1 45353 
2 56454 
2 45645 
3 65756 
3 67565 
3 87865 
3 38932 
4 36468 
4 45332
```

Expected Output is

```
1 34534 
2 56454 
3 65756 
4 36468
```

I need to take all the fist number for each Id.

**How can i write a Query to achieve this?** I am not expert in SQL. :(

Note: Using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Number FROM
    (SELECT ID, Number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Number) RN FROM MyTable) Base
    WHERE Base.RN = 1
```

Clearly `MyTable` is the name of your table

Ah... Clearly `2 56454` is impossible. You can only get `2 45645`. Order in an sql table is an illusion unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the SQL server can reorder the rows howerer it wants.

Comment: @w0lf I didn't know of SQL Fiddle... Is it new? An year ago I searched for something similar but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: I've been using it for about half a year I think. It's great for collaborating on small SQL scenarios like this one.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test12 t1 CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT TOP 1 Number
                                FROM dbo.test12 t2
                                WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
                                ) o
WHERE t1.Number = o.Number
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f162/1)